# Argument missing..

Tags: functional-analysis

claim: X complete metric space $\Rightarrow$ X not meagre

Proof: Assume X meagre$\Rightarrow X=\bigcup_{n\geq1} A_n, ($closure$(A_n))^°\neq \emptyset\forall n\Rightarrow X=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}$closure$(A_n)\Rightarrow$ contradiction to the Baire THM.

I don't understand the last two steps. Why should I have a contradiction?
Thanks

Comment: I doubt if the claim is true. If $X$ is countable and is given the discrete metric, then $X$ is complete and meagre.

Comment: I see.. ok now I'm more confused :) I had it as an example in the lecture.. but your point seems me to be good

Comment: I guess that might be possible if $X$ is also connected (and has at least two points).

Comment: I think the problem of your example was that with the trivial metric point are open and closed. this means that $A_n=\{x\}$ has int(closure($A_n$))={x}. and so $A_n$ aren't nowhere dense.

Comment: You are right. my bad.